# General Networking Questions

Tags: udp, ip, baseline

I am currently preparing myself for the exam in Networking and I got some questions:

```
Are both UDP and IP unreliable to the same degree? Why or Why not?

What is DC component and baseline wandering in digital transmission?
```

I am actually not very good in physics - so if someone could give me the answer for the second question in "easy English" that would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning the UDP/IP question:
Both are not of the same degree of 
unreliability.

UDP is more unreliable, because its header is simple and there is no error detection mechanism.

But IP uses pseudoheader and error correction and detection facilities. IPv4 is unreliable, but not as UDP.

Answer (score 2):

As for the digital transmission:

Baseline wandering: in decoding a digital signal, the receiver calculates a running average of the received signal power. This average is called the baseline. Now, when we have a long string of 0s or 1s it causes drift in the baseline (Baseline Wandering).

DC Component: when the digital signal is constant for a while, the spectrum creates very low frequencies, these frequencies around zero is called the DC Component.